# I need to check the fill color of 2 svg elements and do something if they meet criteria

Tags: javascript

I want to check if two svg elements have a certain fill color and then move another svg element. Cant get it to work

```
function calculate() {
var state1 = document.getElementById("#stateButton1"),
        maturity1 = document.getElementById("#maturityButton1");

if ((state1.style.fill = "#e1532d") && (maturity1.style.fill = "#e1532d")) {
    TweenMax.to('#star,#star1', 0.1, {y:0});
    TweenMax.to('#star,#star1', 0.1, {y:-290});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your syntax.

`document.getElementById` does not not a hash `#` symbol.

You are setting a value rather than performing an equality check when you use `element.style.fill = ...` instead of `element.style.fill === ...`

This should work:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="stateButton1" height="100" width="100" fill="#e1532d">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
  <svg id="maturityButton1" height="100" width="100" fill="#e1532d">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function calculate() {
    var state1 = document.getElementById("stateButton1"),
    var maturity1 = document.getElementById("maturityButton1");

  if (state1.getFill() === '#e1532d' && maturity1.getFill() === '#e1532d') {
        TweenMax.to('#star,#star1', 0.1, {y:0});
    TweenMax.to('#star,#star1', 0.1, {y:-290});
  }
}

function getFill(el) {
    if (!el) return null; 
  return el.getAttribute('fill');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1zLgw2d/6/

Answer (score 0):

In this line `(state1.style.fill = "#e1532d") && (maturity1.style.fill = "#e1532d")` you're assigning a value to `fill` properties with `=` operator instead of comparing. In JavaScript equality comparison operator is `===`.